# Time Format Contains Colon(:) Not supported by iOS 12.2

Tags: ios, swift, nsdateformatter

I'm using `iPhone SE` which contains `iOS 12.2`. I'm converting my date to following time format (`h:MM a`) which convert correct time but colon(:) between hour and minute removed.

My code as follows to convert time:

```
static func getDateInWithoutTimeZone(format: String, from timeStamp: Int64) -> String? {
    let date = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: TimeInterval(timeStamp))
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.locale = NSLocale.current
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = format //Specify your format that you want
    return dateFormatter.string(from: date)
}
```

I'm using this method to convert time, where timestamp contain `UNIX` time value like `1555395758`

I'm using above function as following:

```
guard let time = Date.getDateInWithoutTimeZone(format: "h:MM a", from: 1555395758) else {
    return
}
```

And getting following output:

```
1104 AM
```

Am I doing anything wrong ? Or Is it issue with `iOS 12.2`?

Comment: MM - > month not minutes

Comment: I tried your code I am not faced any issues,its works fine for me, change your format `dateFormat = "h:mm a"`

Comment: Strange... I got `8:22 AM` when run your code in playground. Yes, I change `"h:MM a"` to `"h:mm a"` but it doesn't matter, colon as a separator is still here...

Comment: You have to set locale to POSIX if you want to handle 12h vs 24h correctly. Otherwise the format will be overwritten by system settings.

Comment: Hey @sagar, Please check my answer. Your device is on 24 hour format thats why you got "1104 AM" . value.

Comment: Its date format issue. not an iOS issue.

Comment: It's display proper in simulator `iPhone 8 - 12.1`

Comment: its not "h:MM a" its  "hh:mm a" if you need 12H format 
if you need 24 hour then  "HH:mm"

Comment: @SagarChauhan your method name it is misleading. What does `getDateInWithoutTimeZone` mean to you? If you don't set the date formatter timezone you will be using the current timezone. IF you want to get UTC time you would need to set the timezone to zero seconds from gmt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change date format `h:MM a` to `hh:mm a`

Please refer below code.

```
static func getDateInWithoutTimeZone(format: String, from timeStamp: Int64) -> String? {
    let date = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: TimeInterval(timeStamp))
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = format //Specify your format that you want
    return dateFormatter.string(from: date)
}

guard let time = getDateInWithoutTimeZone(format: "hh:mm a", from: 1555395758) else {
    return
}
print(time)
```

[image: Console Log]

> MM which stands for months, not minutes.

Comment: locale should be `"en_US_POSIX"`. Btw Note that this method will create a new DateFormatter every single time you call it.

Comment: @iMHiteshSurani, Have you tried in Real device with iOS 12.2 ?

Comment: Yes, iPhone 8P With iOS 12.1 Working fine with my device.

Comment: Also, checked for 12 and 24 Hours format and verify with https://www.epochconverter.com/

Answer (score 1):

If you want to display hours and minutes (plus am/pm) your format string should be `"h:mm a"`. Whenever you want to include charaters that are not directly format specifiers, it is recommended to include them in single quotes. So you could also use `"h':'mm a"`. Note that the specifier you used in your example includes `MM` (capital M) which stands for months, not minutes.

Comment: As I mentioned, you _could_ follow the general recommendation here (meaning it's not required in this case).